# Putting a wrapper around a group of elements in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm using XSLT to transform an XML document from one doctype to another.  In simplified form, I have something that looks like this:

```
<section>
    <title>Title</title>
    <a>content1</a>
    <a>content2</a>
    <a>content3</a>
    <a>content4</a>
    <b>other content</b>
    <a>content5</a>
    <a>content6</a>
    <a>content7</a>
    <c>other content</c>
    <a>content8</a>
    <a>content9</a>
    <a>content10</a>
</section>
```

What I want is to place a wrapper around the groups of `<a>` elements, so the translated result looks like this:

```
<section>
    <title>Title</title>
    <a-wrapper>
        <a>content1</a>
        <a>content2</a>
        <a>content3</a>
        <a>content4</a>
    </a-wrapper>
    <b>other content</b>
    <a-wrapper>
        <a>content5</a>
        <a>content6</a>
        <a>content7</a>
    </a-wrapper>
    <c>other content</c>
    <a-wrapper>
        <a>content8</a>
        <a>content9</a>
        <a>content10</a>
    </a-wrapper>
</section>
```

My current template looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(preceding-sibling::a)">
            <xsl:element name="a-wrapper">
                <xsl:element name="a">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::a[generate-id(preceding-sibling::a[last()]) = generate-id(current())]"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This gets me partway there.  The problem is that the select clause in the apply-templates tag is getting all of the `<a>` tags, when I want it to stop at the first non-`<a>` tag, i.e., the processing of the first `<a>` tag is placing all 10 `<a>` tags within the first `<a-wrapper>`, when I only want the first four.  This also has the effect of inserting nested `<a-wrapper>` tags, like the one generated by the fifth `<a>` tag, and that's not allowed by the DTD.

So the question is, how do I select a subset of following-siblings that ends with the first non-`<a>` tag?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming, from you example, you want to 'wrap' everything except the first element within the **section** element, you could write a template to match the section element, and then start off by selecting the child elements whose name differs from their most preceding sibling

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="*[position() > 1]
              [local-name() != local-name(preceding-sibling::*[1])]" mode="wrapper" />
```

Then, within this 'wrapper' template, you can create your wrapper element, and then start off by selecting the first element to wrap

```
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}-wrapper">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*" mode="copy"/>
  </xsl:element>
```

And within this "copy" template, you would copy the element, and then recursively select the next element, should it have the same name

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="following-sibling::*[1][local-name() = local-name(current())]" mode="copy"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*[position() &gt; 1][local-name() != local-name(preceding-sibling::*[1])]" mode="wrapper"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*" mode="wrapper">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}-wrapper">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*" mode="copy"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy">
      <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][local-name() = local-name(current())]" mode="copy"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<section>
   <title>Title</title>
   <a-wrapper>
      <a>content1</a>
      <a>content2</a>
      <a>content3</a>
      <a>content4</a>
   </a-wrapper>
   <b-wrapper>
      <b>other content</b>
   </b-wrapper>
   <a-wrapper>
      <a>content5</a>
      <a>content6</a>
      <a>content7</a>
   </a-wrapper>
   <c-wrapper>
      <c>other content</c>
   </c-wrapper>
   <a-wrapper>
      <a>content8</a>
      <a>content9</a>
      <a>content10</a>
   </a-wrapper>
</section>
```

Note how there is no hard-coding of any specific element names in this solution, which should hopefully give you more flexibility.

EDIT: As you actually only want to wrap the 'a' elements, this makes it actually simpler. You could have a template to match the first occurrence of a group of 'a' elements like so

```
<xsl:template match="a[preceding-sibling::*[1][not(self::a)]]">
```

Then you would copy the element, and the following 'a' elements in a similar manner to before.

Try this XSLT instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="a[preceding-sibling::*[1][not(self::a)]]">
        <a-wrapper>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="self::a" mode="copy"/>
        </a-wrapper>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="a" />

   <xsl:template match="a" mode="copy">
      <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::a]" mode="copy"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I actually *don't* want to wrap anything other than <a>.  But I should be able to de-genericize this to only apply to the <a> tags.  I'll do some testing and confirm.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake for not properly reading the question. I have amended my answer to show how this may be done.

Answer (score 0):

I truly appreciate your efforts on my behalf.  And it's my turn to apologize, as the problem statement was incomplete.  I neglected to note that I'm converting [a] to a different tag - let's call it [a2].  Other conversions are happening as well, including [section] to [sect1].

In the meantime, a different source has proposed a solution that works for me.  It looks like this, in fragment form:

```
<xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:element name="sect1">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::a)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <xsl:element name="a-wrapper">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```